# LINQ OrderBy and StringBuilder

Tags: linq, stringbuilder

I have the following custom class

```
public class Album
{
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a List of that type that I sorted by Location then by DateTime

```
List<Album> SortedList = list
  .OrderBy(o => o.Location)
  .ThenBy(o => o.DateTime)
  .ToList();
```

now I need to have a StringBuilder that will append the index number beside the location but the index number should be dependent on Location, not on the List

For example, my list contains:

```
> a | London | 12:00:00 AM
> b | London | 1:00:00 AM
> c | Warsaw | 1:30:00 AM
> d | Warsaw | 1:45:00 AM
```

My StringBuilder must be:

```
> London01
> London02
> Warsaw01
> Warsaw02
```

I have tried using this but it returns the index number of the list

```
var query = SortedList.IndexOf(list.SingleOrDefault(i => i.DateTime == a.DateTime));
```

Just want to know how can I achieve my needed requirement?

**Update:** This is my complete code with the part wherein I should place the stringbuilder:

```
public static string Solution(string S)
    {
        string[] group = S.Split("\r\n");
        List<Album> list = new List<Album>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string g in group)
        {
            string[] album = g.Split(',');
            Album a = new Album();
            a.PhotoName = album[0];
            a.Location = album[1];
            a.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(album[2]);
            list.Add(a);
        }

        List<Album> SortedList = list.OrderBy(o => o.Location).ThenBy(o => o.DateTime).ToList();

        foreach (string g in group)
        {
            string[] album = g.Split(',');
            Album a = new Album();
            a.PhotoName = album[0];
            string[] photodetails = a.PhotoName.Split('.');
            a.Location = album[1];
            a.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(album[2]);

  //this is the part where I must figure out how to build the string

           // var query = SortedList.IndexOf(list.SingleOrDefault(i => i.DateTime == a.DateTime));

            sb.AppendLine(a.Location + query + "." + photodetails[1]);

        }

        string res = sb.ToString();
        return res;
    }
```

string S is in this form:

```
@"photo.jpg, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:08:15
john.png, London, 2015-06-20 15:13:22
myFriends.png, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:07:13
Eiffel.jpg, Paris, 2015-07-23 08:03:02
pisatower.jpg, Paris, 2015-07-22 23:59:59
BOB.jpg, London, 2015-08-05 00:02:03"
```

and the resulting StringBuilder must be

```
Warsaw01
London01
Warsaw02
Paris01
Paris02
London02
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `GroupBy` and the `Select` function which also includes the index. Than `SelectMany` to flatten it out.

```
var result = list
              .OrderBy(o => o.Location)
              .ThenBy(o => o.DateTime)
              .GroupBy(o => o.Location)
              .SelectMany(o => o.Select((x,i) => x.Location + (i + 1).ToString("d2")));
```

And if you want it to a string, no need for a StringBuilder, just do:

```
var resultString = string.Join("\n", result);
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include my complete code. Just don't know where to place it in.

Comment: I have updated my question again. Basically, String S is input from the user and the resulting string must be dependent on his input.

Comment: I answered your original question but don't understand what you want now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `GroupBy` and `Aggregate` extension methods

```
var output = 
    albums.GroupBy(album => album.Location)
          .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
          .SelectMany(group => group.OrderBy(album => album.DateTime)
                                    .Select((album, i) => $"{album.PhotoName}{(i+1):00}"))
          .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                     (builder, item) => builder.AppendLine(item))
          .ToString();
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include my complete code. Just don't know where to place it in.